# PyCharm does not react after stopping Python script

Tags: python, pycharm

I just started to use PyCharm and there is one thing that I don't understand. When I stop a Python scipt (for training ANNs with Keras and Tensorflow) by pressing the red stop button, the script is stopped but PyCharm does not really react any more. I can't execute the script again and I have to go to the task manager in Windows to kill the whole PyCharm programm and start restart it which is quite inconvenient. Any idea as to why this is happening? The same script with the same data can easily be stopped when using another editor (e.g. Spyder).

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

**Reminder**: Does nobody have any idea how to stop a script in PyCharm?

Comment: In my experience, PyCharm has a harder time killing the process if the script uses multiple processes (which your model training is probably doing). Not sure why, but it seems that the stop signal is not propagated to the processes properly. You can circumvent this by pressing the skull symbol which terminates the process instead of gracefully ending it (tbh, I am not sure what the actual difference is).

Comment: @CHecht: Thanks Hecht for your answer. Unfortunately the skull button has no effect at all (same as stop button). So the script and process is not stopped and I have to use the taskmanager to shut down the whole PyCharm editor and restart it again.

Comment: Spyder has its own debugger (it was recently re-implemented being a top requested feature) so there's no relation to the PyCharm debugger. In the task manager you should be able to terminate whatever Python process was launched without having to terminate the whole PyCharm IDE.

Comment: @bad_coder: Thanks Bad Coder for your comment. First of all I think there should be a way to stop the script in PyCharm other than using the taskmanager as this is quite primitive especially considering that PyCharm claims to be for professional developers. Moreover, I had tried your suggested way of terminating the Python process in the taskmanager before posting my question. Acutally this is not posssible. When I do this, PyCharm does not react at all (even worse than pressing the Stop button).

Comment: I can't really diagnose that, looks like you're working with CUDA so who knows how inter-process communication is being done in the background. It might work with one OS but not the other, we're also requesting that PyCharm be able to debug anything and keep up with the ever changing Python language. Personally I'd be happy just to have the imports and linter get some of the standard library stuff right. Also, if you're working with multiprocessing it's likely you should be using [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) or something like that.

Comment: It'd advise searching the [JetBrains tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) for CUDA specific problems before searching through StackOverflow to see if there's some specific debugger setting to make this work. Also Keras and Tensorflow come with specific build distributions so there might be a specific problem with that.

Comment: @bad_coder: Thanks Bad coder for your comment and effort. I really appreciate it. I don't work with Cuda. This just comes automatically when using Keras and Tensorflow. And as said before, in Spyder it is not a problem at all to stop the process. But okay, I understand that my question might be to specific for others answer. Still maybe someone else has an idea how to tackle this. If not then I just have to end and restart PyCharm again all the time when I want to exit the program.

Comment: An alternative is to close the tab in which the debugger operates. That can sometimes mean that the process still lives, but at least you can continue working if you then restart the debugger (tested on Linux).